# Avoid interpolation of data when plotting map using latitude and longitude instead of provided x-y coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have a 2-d numpy array with with some data, in x and y coordinates. With each x and y point is also associated a latitude and a longitude (also 2-d numpy arrays). There are some values in the oceans, but not over land.
When I plot the data in x and y coordinates, I get the following:

`plt.imshow(data)`

[image: Using imshow]

Then, I want to plot this data on a map using lon-lat coordinates. If I do so as following, I get some plotted data on land, since some interpolation is operated.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
plt.pcolor(lon, lat, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
```

[image]

I obtain the same for any type of plot that I can use on a map (pcolormesh, contour, contourf).

How can this be avoided since no data would show on land, where values should be Nans?

Thank you!

The data is part of the CMIP6 project. It can be accessed through Pangeo by accessing ocean.pangeo.io and running the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import zarr
import gcsfs
import intake
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster

cluster = KubeCluster()
cluster.adapt(minimum=1, maximum=20, interval='2s', wait_count=10)
client = Client(cluster)
client

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NCAR/intake-esm-datastore/master/catalogs/pangeo-cmip6.json'
col = intake.open_esm_datastore(url)
col_hist = col.search(variable_id='o2', table_id='Omon', experiment_id='historical')
dict_hist = col_hist.to_dataset_dict(zarr_kwargs={'consolidated': True})

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

models = list(dict_hist.keys())
model = models[5]
ds = dict_hist[model]
sub1 = ds.o2.sel(member_id=ds.member_id.values[0], time=ds.time.values[0])
sub2 = sub1.sel(lev=100, method='nearest')

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
q = sub2.plot(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), x='lon', y='lat', vmin=0, vmax=0.4, cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.5})
ax.set_global(); ax.coastlines();
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data somewhere? My guess is something is up with the longitude coordinates (CartoPy sometimes has an issue with (-180, 180) vs. (0, 360))

Comment: @DopplerShift I added a sample of the coordinate data. I don't think this is the only problem since the features fit with the coastlines.

Comment: I think there is some relation to the coordinates, since you can see some unrealistic data starting at +80 longitude, which is where the coordinates begin. I think it's going to be really helpful to be sample to see the actual data file to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @DopplerShift Ok. The data is part of the CMIP6 project and is associated with very large files. I added a way to access the files in the question,

Comment: I think it's something to do with the multi-dimensional `lat, lon` coordinates. See http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html and http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#multidimensional-coordinates. I'm not entirely sure how to fix it though...

Comment: I tried using `sub2.plot(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), x='x', y='y')` because that seems to be what is suggested from the documentation (linked above) but that doesn't fix it..

Answer (score 0):

Edited to account for comments on data.

The issue with the filled areas is one of wrapping. What you see is data plotting from e.g. +179.8 (right side of plot) to -178.4 (left side of plot)--CartoPy is not correctly clipping, so you have long streaks of data plotting across the map. In areas with other data plotted, these streaks are covered. Where you have no data plotted (i.e. on land) the streaks show through.

One work-around is to adjust the origin of the projection, which can eliminate some of those lines. I've had some success with small adjustments (~1 degree), but the best would be to make it so that the left and right edges of the original domain of the data are the left and right edges of the plot. For this dataset the left edge is +73.5 longitude, so we want the origin to be that +180, which is -107.5 longitude:

```
import intake
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NCAR/'
       'intake-esm-datastore/master/catalogs/pangeo-cmip6.json')

col = intake.open_esm_datastore(url)
col_hist = col.search(variable_id='o2', table_id='Omon', experiment_id='historical')
dict_hist = col_hist.to_dataset_dict(zarr_kwargs={'consolidated': True})

models = list(dict_hist.keys())
model = models[5]
ds = dict_hist[model]
sub1 = ds.o2.sel(member_id=ds.member_id.values[0], time=ds.time.values[0])
sub2 = sub1.sel(lev=100, method='nearest')

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson(central_longitude=-107.5))
q = sub2.plot(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), x='longitude', y='latitude',
              vmin=0, vmax=0.4, cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.5})
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
```

which gives me this image:

[image: data plot]

Ideally, CartoPy would handle this correctly, but right now there are lots of issues with this (like [this one](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1419) for example).

Comment: This is weird, when I run the code I get a DataArray which doesn't have `latitude` or `longitude`. All packages the same except matplotlib is 3.1.1

Comment: @DopplerShift Actually I should have selected model number 6. Number 5 gives me the same thing as you, and model 6 the image above.
`model = models[6]`

Comment: I can reproduce with the information about `models[6]`, so I've corrected my answer above.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.
If Cartopy is the problem, is there a way to make it work with Basemap instead? I tried the following code but I still get the same wrapping problem.

`m = Basemap(projection='mill')`
`x, y = m(sub2.longitude.values, sub2.latitude.values)`
`q = m.pcolor(x,y,sub2.values,vmin=0,vmax=0.4)`
`m.drawcoastlines()`

Comment: If Basemap doesn't work out of the box, then I don't see any point in trying harder with it since Basemap is on the way out. My example showed how to get a reasonable plot with CartoPy, so that'd be the way I would go.